# Docusaurus: Wrapping custom root in ChakraProvider breaks my mdx pages

Tags: chakra-ui, docusaurus

I'm building a site with [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/) and want to use some [Chakra-UI](https://chakra-ui.com/) components in my code.  Chakra-ui requires wrapping the root of any app in a `ChakraProvider` component (for instance, in an application built with create-react-app: https://chakra-ui.com/guides/getting-started/cra-guide#2-provider-setup).

So, in an attempt to make Chakra-ui work with Docusaurus, I've followed Docusaurus's instructions here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling#wrapper-your-site-with-root, and created a custom root at `/src/theme/Root.js`.  I've then tried to wrap the app in a `ChakraProvider` like so:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';


export default function Root({children}) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      {children}
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

Saving this code and then running `npx docusaurus start` results in a site in which my MDX pages aren't working right.  Specifically, the headings (e.g. `# This is a Heading`) are not getting picked up as headings and converted to html as I expect.

I should also say that the headings are the only MDX elements that seem to be broken here!  All the other elements that I have on my pages are rendering correctly.

Help?

Comment: Tried wrapping the specific Chakra components I was using in their own `ChakraProvider` components, rather than wrapping the root of the app.  That does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `resetCss={false}` to the ChakraProvider tag should fix the problem.

```
<ChakraProvider resetCSS={false}>{children}</ChakraProvider>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).